# About region / zone of Google Compute Engine's VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an instance which was created in Australia region, the zone is `australia-southeast1-a`. However, I find that the External IP is still in US:
[image]

Had tried creating another instance in another region (asia), and logined using ssh, haven't noticed any significant difference in latency, the responses are both not very fast.

My question is, have I correctly setup the region to Australia? Or is there any configuration that I have missed?

Comment: You can test the latency from Australia to confirm where the external IP actually is.

Comment: @Dagang I just created an instance in `us-west1-a`, very interesting that it's even faster than the instance in `australia-southeast1-a` (I'm connecting from Melbourne).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup on the VM and its configuration are perfectly fine. You have your hardware physically located in the Australian region. Your concern over IP’s location is just a mere confusion. This had happened to most of the customers.

Most of the external Geo IP services are depending upon the SWIP database. And for this reason, most of the Google’s IPs are SWIP’ed to the  Mountain View, CA. Because of this, even for a VM which is created outside (in your case Australian Region) the US shows its IP location as in the US.

Furthermore, you can also go through [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg) Google discussion thread which will give you more comments on this matter.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use gce to get data from `www.luxbet.com`, which is not accessible outside of Australia. I will try an Australia VPN to see if it can solve this problem.